# How to compare properties between two objects

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two similar classes : `Person` , `PersonDto`

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Serial { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

&

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Serial { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have two objects of both by equal values.

```
    var person = new Person { Name = null , Serial = 123, Date1 = DateTime.Now.Date, Date2 = DateTime.Now.Date };
    var dto = new PersonDto { Name = "AAA", Serial = 123, Date1 = DateTime.Now.Date, Date2 = DateTime.Now.Date };
```

I need to check value of all properties in two classes by reflection. My final goal is defined difference value of this properties.

```
    IList diffProperties = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var item in person.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (item.GetValue(person, null) != dto.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(dto, null))
            diffProperties.Add(item);
    }
```

I did this, but result is not satisfactory. Count of `diffProperties` for result was `4`but count of my expect was `1`.

Of course all properties can have null values.

I need to a solution generic.
What must do I?

Comment: Hi dear Ehsan, I believe you are on a wrong track, having two classes with exactly same implementation is totally wrong idea, you need just one class and several (2 here) objects of it.
You are checking let's say a serial with another serial which check their storage place in RAM not their real VALUE, consider that checking values is a different content in OOP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to stick with comparison via reflection you should not use != (reference equality which will fail most of comparisons for boxed results of GetProperty calls) but instead use [static Object.Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.100%29).

Sample how to use Equals method to compare two object in your reflection code.

```
 if (!Object.Equals(
     item.GetValue(person, null),
     dto.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(dto, null)))
 { 
   diffProperties.Add(item);
 }
```

Comment: +1: actually changed my mind (and edited the answer) - this is exactly why OPs code was not working - != does reference comparison which pretty much always failes for boxed results of reflectin "get property", correct call to Equals does comparisions in expected way.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider making the `Person` class implement the `IComparable` interface and implementing the `CompareTo(Object obj)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [IEquatable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at you classes not all values can be null you have a nullable long.
But that said.

I also made something like this and used [this website](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2007/08/03/use-reflection-to-compare-the-properties-of-two-objects/) for it. Just make it so that it can accept 2 different objects. I can't share my code because of licensing sorry.

Comment: -1. Please provide some information - if you want to share link - post as comment, otherwise please make sure at least summary of link's content is in the answer.